# If my vba encounters an error, how to move onto the next procedure?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a report that i run for a Customer who has several accounts with how much they owe for each account.  This macros filters, sorts by one account number, grabs all rows pertaining to that account number, cuts it, and pastes it into another sheet. And it keeps doing this till all the accounts are in separate sheets.  So:

```
Sub findsort()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    With ws
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="905539971"


    Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, 
    .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng.Copy Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A2")
    rng.EntireRow.Delete

    .UsedRange.AutoFilter

    End With

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select


    Range("A1:O1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "ROCKTENN CP LLC (3PL)"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    With ws
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="905135784"


    Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, 
    .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng.Copy Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A2")
    rng.EntireRow.Delete

    .UsedRange.AutoFilter

    End With

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select


    Range("A1:O1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "ROCK-TENN RECYCLING (3PL)"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

The Problem is sometimes not all the accounts show up so if the macros searches for "905539971" and its not there because they don't owe anything, the macros gets an error.

So my question is, do i have to nest each one of these procedures within a VBA that tells it if it doesn't find that account number to just move onto the next one?  If so, what would be the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the existence of the account before moving on to apply the filter and such. See below.

```
With ws

    If Not Intersect(.UsedRange,.Columns(2)).Find("905539971", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then 

       .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="905539971"

        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, 
          .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        rng.Copy Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A2")
        rng.EntireRow.Delete

        .UsedRange.AutoFilter

    End If

End With
```